# MongoDB Aggregate Sum Each Key on a Subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents with this schema, each document is per product per day:

```js
{
    _id:{},
    app_id:'DHJFK67JDSJjdasj909',
    date:'2014-08-07',
    event_count:32423,
    event_count_per_type: {
        0:322,
        10:4234,
        20:653,
        30:7562
    }
}
```

I would like to get the sum of each event_type for a particular date_range.
This is the output I am looking for where each event type has been summed across all the documents. The keys for event_count_per_type can be anything, so I need something that can loop through each of them as opposed to be having to be implicit with their names.

```js
{
    app_id:'DHJFK67JDSJjdasj909',
    event_count:324236456,
    event_count_per_type: {
        0:34234222,
        10:242354,
        20:456476,
        30:56756
    }
}
```

I have been trying several queries so far, this is the best I have got so far but the sub document values are not summed:

```js
db.events.aggregate(
{
    $match: {app_id:'DHJFK67JDSJjdasj909'}
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            app_id:'$app_id',
        },
        event_count: {$sum:'$event_count'},
        event_count_per_type: {$sum:'$event_count_per_type'}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id:0,
        app_id:'$_id.app_id',
        event_count:1,
        event_count_per_type:1
    }
}
)
```

The output I am seeing is a value of 0 for the event_count_per_type key, instead of an object. I could modify the schema so the keys are on the top level of the document but that will still mean that I need to have an entry in the group statement for each key, which as I do not know what the key names will be I cannot do.

Any help would be appreciated, I am willing to change my schema if need be and also to try mapReduce (although from the documentation it seems like the performance is bad.)

Comment: if you don't know the key names in the subdocument then you cannot do this with aggregation (you could with map-reduce though).  Are you sure the key name can be *anything* at all?  or is it the case that it can only be a number in a certain range?  Can it be "foo"?  Or can it only be a number between 0 and 59 or some such?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky it will be an int between 0 and 100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated, processing documents like this is not possible with the aggregation framework unless you are actually going to supply all of the keys, such as:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$app_id",
       "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
       "0": { "$sum": "$event_count_per_type.0" },
       "10": { "$sum": "$event_count_per_type.10" }
       "20": { "$sum": "$event_count_per_type.20" }
       "30": { "$sum": "$event_count_per_type.30" }
   }}
])
```

But you do of course have to explicitly specify **every** key you wish to work on. This is true of both the aggregation framework and general query operations in MongoDB, as to access elements notated in this "sub-document" form you need to specify the "exact path" to the element in order to do anything with it.

The aggregation framework and general queries have no concept of "traversal", which mean they cannot process "each key" of a document. That requires a language construct in order to do which is not provided in these interfaces.

Generally speaking though, using a "key name" as a data point where it's name actually represents a "value" is a bit of an "anti-pattern". A better way to model this would be to use an array and represent your "type" as a value by itself:

```js
{
    "app_id": "DHJFK67JDSJjdasj909",
    "date: ISODate("2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "event_count": 32423,
    "events": [
        { "type": 0,  "value": 322  },
        { "type": 10, "value": 4234 },
        { "type": 20, "value": 653  },
        { "type": 30, "value": 7562 }
    ]
}
```

Also noting that the "date" is now a proper date object rather than a string, which is also something that is good practice to do. This sort of data though is easy to process with the aggregation framework:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "app_id": "$app_id",
            "type": "$events.type"
        },
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "value": { "$sum": "$value" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.app_id",
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "events": { "$push": { "type": "$_id.type", "value": "$value" } }
    }}
])
```

That shows a two stage grouping that first gets the totals per "type" without specifying each "key" since you no longer have to, then returns as a single document per "app_id" with the results in an array as they were originally stored. This data form is generally much more flexible for looking at certain "types" or even the "values" within a certain range.

Where you cannot change the structure then your only option is mapReduce. This allows you to "code" the traversal of the keys, but since this requires JavaScript interpretation and execution it is not as fast as the aggregation framework:

```js
db.events.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(
            this.app_id,
            {
                "event_count": this.event_count,
                "event_count_per_type": this.event_count_per_type
            }
        );
    },
    function(key,values) {

        var reduced = { "event_count": 0, "event_count_per_type": {} };

        values.forEach(function(value) {
            for ( var k in value.event_count_per_type ) {
                if ( !redcuced.event_count_per_type.hasOwnProperty(k) )
                    reduced.event_count_per_type[k] = 0;
                reduced.event_count_per_type += value.event_count_per_type;
            }
            reduced.event_count += value.event_count;
        })
    },
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

That will essentially traverse and combine the "keys" and sum up the values for each one found.

So you options are either:

1. Change the structure and work with standard queries and aggregation.
2. Stay with the structure and require JavaScript processing and mapReduce.

It depends on your actual needs, but in most cases restructuring yields benefits.

Comment: Thank you, thats brilliant! I am still in the early stages of this application and so I will go ahead with changing the schema. I actually have another array that I want to merge at the same time called unqiue_event_count_per_type but the second $unwind is causing the $sum to double count the records when I include it in the first $group _id. Would I have to do this as a second query and merge the two results in code?

Comment: @Irfan That sounds like another question and is better expressed by posting a new question with all of the details. Don't forget to accept the answers that help you as quite of a few of us look to see if there are accepted answers in your history. Merging two arrays is possible, but the whole question deserves another full answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201157/mongo-sum-compounded-when-doing-unwind-and-then-group-on-multiple-fields