# mongo $sum compounded when doing $unwind and then $group on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure

```
{
    "app_id": "DHJFK67JDSJjdasj909",
    "date": ISODate("2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "event_count": 100,
    "events": [
        { "type": 0,  "value": 12  },
        { "type": 10, "value": 24 },
        { "type": 20, "value": 36  },
        { "type": 30, "value": 43 }
    ],
    "unique_events": [
        { "type": 0,  "value": 5  },
        { "type": 10, "value": 8 },
        { "type": 20, "value": 12  },
        { "type": 30, "value": 56 }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get a sum of event_counts and also the values for unique_events and events per type. This is the kind of output I am expecting where the event_count and each events and unique_events value has been summed per type.

```
{
    "app_id": "DHJFK67JDSJjdasj909",
    "date": ISODate("2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "event_count": 4345,
    "events": [
        { "type": 0,  "value": 624  },
        { "type": 10, "value": 234 },
        { "type": 20, "value": 353 },
        { "type": 30, "value": 472 }
    ],
    "unique_events": [
        { "type": 0,  "value": 433  },
        { "type": 10, "value": 554 },
        { "type": 20, "value": 645  },
        { "type": 30, "value": 732 }
    ]
}
```

This is my query

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "app_id": "$app_id",
            "type": "$events.type"
            "unique_type": "$unique_events.type"
        },
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "event_value": { "$sum": "$events.value" },
        "unique_event_value": { "$sum": "$unique_events.value" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.app_id",
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "events": { "$push": { "type": "$_id.type", "value": "$event_value" } }
        "unique_events": { "$push": { "type": "$_id.unique_type", "value": "$unique_event_value" } }
    }}
])
```

The problem is that using two $unwinds and then grouping by both events and unique_events is causing the $sum to be compounded and much too large. Is there some way I can fix this using mongo or do I have to run two queries and then merge the two result sets in code.

Thanks

Irfan

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but it sounds like the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) or [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) operator might help you to preserve arrays through groupings.

Comment: is this your actual aggregation? you only have one $unwind here.

Comment: will events and unique events arrays always be the same in size?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I don't think that matters. As well as looking at the overall question the solution is fairly self evident. But considering re-modelling of data should always be an option. Especially when general queries want to "combine" multiple arrays from documents.

Comment: @NeilLunn it matters a lot, actually - if unique represents an aggregation of events (by unique whatever) then it can simplify the pipeline *significantly*

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I don't agree. While "remodeling data" is important, the most important thing here is providing a solution. Good answers suggest both. Which I believe I do on a regular basis. So please give me a break rather than being so critical all of the time. That is a reasonable ask.

Comment: try your pipeline with different sizes of arrays - it changes the output of event_count even though top level event_count is identical in both.  But actually your event_count is over-counting based on the length of the two arrays.  Shouldn't event_counts only be added based on the number of actual top level documents that match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simple enough really, to sum the results for each array it's just a matter of discerning between which is which and "combining the elements". In short you should probably be doing this in you documents anyway as should be evident from the first pipeline stage(s).

So for MongoDB 2.6 and greater there are some helper methods:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "app_id": 1,
        "event_count": 1,
        "all_events": {
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$events",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "type": "$$el.type",
                        "value": "$$el.value",
                        "class": { "$literal": "A" }
                    }
                }},
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$unique_events",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "type": "$$el.type",
                        "value": "$$el.value",
                        "class": { "$literal": "B" }
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$all_events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "app_id": "$app_id",
            "class": "$all_events.class",
            "type": "$all_events.type"
        },
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "value": { "$sum": "$all_events.value" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.app_id",
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "events": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.class", "A" ] },
                    { "type": "$_id.type", "value": "$value" },
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "unique_events": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.class", "B" ] },
                    { "type": "$_id.type", "value": "$value" },
                    false
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "event_count": 1,
        "events": { "$setDifference": [ "$events", [false] ] },
        "unique_events": {
            "$setDifference": [ "$unique_events", [false] ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Mostly in the [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) and [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operators. The other ccase is [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), which processes arrays in place. The whole thing there is doing operations on arrays without the use of [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). But those can of course be done in prior versions, it just takes a bit more work:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "app_id": { "$first": "$app_id" },
        "event_count": { "$first": "$event_count" },
        "events": {
            "$push": {
                "type": "$events.type",
                "value": "$events.value",
                "class": { "$const": "A" }
            }
        },
        "unique_events": { "$first": "$unique_events" }            
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$unique_events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "app_id": { "$first": "$app_id" },
        "event_count": { "$first": "$event_count" },
        "events": { "$first": "$events" },
        "unique_events": {
            "$push": {
                "type": "$unique_events.type",
                "value": "$unique_events.value",
                "class": { "$const": "B" }
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "app_id": 1,
        "event_count": 1,
        "events": 1,
        "unique_events": 1,
        "type": { "$const": [ "A","B" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    { "$unwind": "$unique_events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "app_id": { "$first": "$app_id" },
        "event_count": { "$first": "$event_count" },
        "all_events": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "$cond": [
                     { "$eq": [ "$events.class", "$type" ] },
                     {
                         "type": "$events.type",
                         "value": "$events.value",
                         "class": "$events.class"
                     },
                     {
                         "type": "$unique_events.type",
                         "value": "$unique_events.value",
                         "class": "$unique_events.class"
                     }
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$all_events" },
   { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "app_id": "$app_id",
            "class": "$all_events.class",
            "type": "$all_events.type"
        },
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "value": { "$sum": "$all_events.value" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.app_id",
        "event_count": { "$sum": "$event_count" },
        "events": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.class", "A" ] },
                    { "type": "$_id.type", "value": "$value" },
                    false
                ]
            }
        },
        "unique_events": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.class", "B" ] },
                    { "type": "$_id.type", "value": "$value" },
                    false
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    { "$match": { "events": { "$ne": false } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "event_count": { "$first": "$event_count" },
        "events": { "$push": "$events" },
        "unique_events": { "$first": "$unique_events" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$unique_events" },
    { "$match": { "unique_events": { "$ne": false } } },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
        "event_count": { "$first": "$event_count" },
        "events": { "$first": "$events" },
        "unique_events": { "$push": "$unique_events" }
    }}
])
```

That gets you the results you want with each array being "summed" together as well as the master "event_count" with the correct result.

You probably should consider combining both of those arrays with a similar identifier to what has been used in the pipelines as demonstrated. This part is half of the work. The other half is considering that you probably should store pre-aggregated results in a collection somewhere for the best application performance.

Comment: I used the first example, which worked great except that the event_count was compounded as the sum is calculated multiple times. To fix this I moved the event_count into _id. I've edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: @Irfan I Think you will find that your suggested edit was rejected and basically on the count that you have not recognized what `$first` does. In the grouping order which is by `_id`, only the "first" item is being selected. Therefore the same item that appears in the main document before the `$unwind` is processed, which creates multiple documents from the array. In the grouping `_id` or by `$first` it is actually the same.

Comment: I was referring to the the first example which makes use of $setUnion (mongo 2.6+) and not the second example which is for older versions of mongo

Answer (score 2):

You can perform Following Map reduce:
Its not a dynamic solution, i have created `variable` for each  `events` and `unique_events`.
I have saved output in different `collection` using `out: "session_stat"` in `mapReduce` Function.

```
var mapFunction = function() {
                      var key = this.app_id;
                      var value = {                                 
                                    event_count: this.event_count,
                                    events: this.events,
                                    unique_events: this.unique_events
                                   };

                      emit( key, value );
                  };

var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {

                        var reducedObject = {
                                              app_id: key,
                                              events_wise_total: 0,
                                              unique_events_wise_total:0,
                                              total_event_count:0
                                            };

                        var events_wise_total = [];
                        var events_0_total = { type:0, value :0};
                        var events_10_total = { type:10, value :0};
                        var events_20_total = { type:20, value :0};
                        var events_30_total = { type:30, value :0};

                        var unique_events_wise_total = [];
                        var unique_events_0_total = { type:0, value :0};
                        var unique_events_10_total = { type:10, value :0};
                        var unique_events_20_total = { type:20, value :0};
                        var unique_events_30_total = { type:30, value :0};

                        var total_event_count = 0;
                        values.forEach( function(value) {
                                total_event_count += value.event_count;
                                var events = value.events;

                                events.forEach(function(event){
                                                if(event.type == 0){events_0_total.value += event.value;}
                                                if(event.type == 10){events_10_total.value += event.value;}
                                                if(event.type == 20){events_20_total.value += event.value;}
                                                if(event.type == 30){events_30_total.value += event.value;}
                                        });

                                var unique_events = value.unique_events;

                                unique_events.forEach(function(unique_event){
                                                if(unique_event.type == 0){unique_events_0_total.value += unique_event.value;}
                                                if(unique_event.type == 10){unique_events_10_total.value += unique_event.value;}
                                                if(unique_event.type == 20){unique_events_20_total.value += unique_event.value;}
                                                if(unique_event.type == 30){unique_events_30_total.value += unique_event.value;}
                                        }); 
                            }
                          );
                        events_wise_total.push(events_0_total);
                        events_wise_total.push(events_10_total);
                        events_wise_total.push(events_20_total);
                        events_wise_total.push(events_30_total);

                        unique_events_wise_total.push(unique_events_0_total);
                        unique_events_wise_total.push(unique_events_10_total);
                        unique_events_wise_total.push(unique_events_20_total);
                        unique_events_wise_total.push(unique_events_30_total);

                        reducedObject.events_wise_total = events_wise_total;
                        reducedObject.unique_events_wise_total = unique_events_wise_total;
                        reducedObject.total_event_count = total_event_count;

                        return reducedObject;
                     };

var finalizeFunction = function (key, reducedValue) {
                          return reducedValue;
                       };                    

db.GroupBy.mapReduce(
                       mapFunction,
                       reduceFunction,
                       {
                         out: "session_stat",
                         finalize: finalizeFunction
                       });
```

Hope it may be useful

Comment: you can write: `out: {inline:1}` to get output object instead store result in different `collection`