# MongoDB Agregation on Keys of Subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a documents like the following

```
{
  date: ISODate(some-date)
  story: {
     a: 24,
     b: 12
  }
},

{
  date: ISODate(some-date)
  story: {
     b: 16,
     c: 14
  }
}
```

And I want to get the result somewhat like:

```
{
  a: 24,
  b: 28,
  c: 14
}
```

I have looked for this in a lot of places but couldn't find a way to do it. Obviously unwind doesn't work since it's not a subarray. And I can't figure out how to use group in this.

Comment: I think you could do it with a map reduce

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

or with http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/ however I`m not familiar with the latest.

Comment: I am trying to get it with the aggregation pipeline, but no luck so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're grouping over the whole collection, just use a constant value like `null` for the grouping `_id`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        a: {$sum: '$story.a'},
        b: {$sum: '$story.b'},
        c: {$sum: '$story.c'},
    }}
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "a" : 24,
            "b" : 28,
            "c" : 14
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: And if I don't know what the keys could be? Like I don't know if its a or apples.

Comment: That's a much different (and messier) question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187453/mongodb-aggregate-sum-each-key-on-a-subdocument