# MongoDB $sum and $avg of sub documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get $sum and $avg of subdocuments, i would like to get $sum and $avg of Channels[0].. and other channels as well. 
my data structure looks like this

```
{  
   _id : ...  Location : 1,  
   Channels : [   
     {    _id: ...,
          Value: 25
     },   
     {    
          _id: ... ,   
          Value: 39   
     },
     {    
          _id: ..,
          Value: 12   
     }
     ] 
}
```

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit confusing. Are you trying to get the sum and average of all the `Value` elements within the `Channels` element *for each document* in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: Using two groups based this example:
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187453/mongodb-aggregate-sum-each-key-on-a-subdocument)

```
db.records.aggregate(
   [
     { $unwind: "$Channels" },
     { $group: {
           _id: {
               "loc" : "$Location",
               "cId" : "$Channels.Id"
           },
           "value" : {$sum : "$Channels.Value" },
           "average" : {$avg : "$Channels.Value"},
           "maximun" : {$max : "$Channels.Value"},
           "minimum" : {$min : "$Channels.Value"}
     }},
     { $group: {
             _id : "$_id.loc",
           "ChannelsSumary" : { $push : 
               {   "channelId" : '$_id.cId', 
                   "value" :'$value', 
                   "average" : '$average',
                   "maximun" :  '$maximun',
                   "minimum" :  '$minimum'
                   }}
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Solution 2:
there is property i didn't show on my original question that might of help "Channels.Id" independent from "Channels._Id"

```
db.records.aggregate( [ 
    { 
        "$unwind" : "$Channels"
    }, 
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$Channels.Id",
            "documentSum" : { "$sum" : "$Channels.Value" },
            "documentAvg" : { "$avg" : "$Channels.Value" }
         }
    }
] )
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the **sum** and **average** of the `Channels.Value` elements for each document in your collection you will need to use mongodb's [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-introduction/) processing. Further, since `Channels` is an array you will need to use the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator to deconstruct the array.

Assuming that your collection is called `example`, here's how you could get both the document sum and average of the `Channels.Value`s:

```
db.example.aggregate( [ 
    { 
        "$unwind" : "$Channels"
    }, 
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "documentSum" : { "$sum" : "$Channels.Value" },
            "documentAvg" : { "$avg" : "$Channels.Value" }
         }
    }
] )
```

The output from your post's data would be:

```
{ 
    "_id" : SomeObjectIdValue,
    "documentSum" : 76,
    "documentAvg" : 25.333333333333332
}
```

If you have more than one document in your collection then you will see a result row for each document containing a `Channels` array.

Comment: i ran the above code with my db having 10 records each record having 4 channels and it generated an object with an array of 109 items instead of the array size be the length of channels array, but it helped me to get the solution

Comment: You got 109 records? Hmm, that's odd. Anyway, it seems like you do *not* want to group your sum and average by document (i.e., by _id). Instead, you want to group by the index of the Channel. That wasn't clear in your post, but, I understand now.

Comment: thats exactly what i did, I'm sorry i wasnt very specific on my question