# MongoDB mathematic operations with array elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have collection with documents like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : <ObjectId>, 
    "player" : <String>, 
    "params" : [
        ...,
        {
            "name" : "kills", 
            "value" : 10
        },
        {
            "name" : "deaths", 
            "value" : 10
        },
        {
            "name" : "assists", 
            "value" : 10
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to get list of all players with calculated KDA? KDA=(kills+assists)/deaths

For example, like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : <ObjectId>,
    "player" : <String>,
    "kda" : 2.5
},
...
]
```

And how to execute queries on resulted collection? To find all players with KDA>10 etc.
Thanks!

Comment: Would be much better if you had looked up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234394/mongodb-sum-and-avg-of-sub-documents), tried out something and share the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order in your `params` array is expected to be identical across all elements one way would be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "kda": {
            $divide: [
                { $sum: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$params.value", 0 ] },
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$params.value", 2 ] }
                ]},
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$params.value", 1 ] } ] 
        }
    }
})
```

If the order is not known or fixed you can do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "kda": {
            $divide: [
                { $sum: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$params.value", { $indexOfArray: [ "$params.name", "kills" ] } ] },
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ "$params.value", { $indexOfArray: [ "$params.name", "assists" ] } ] }
                ]},
                { $arrayElemAt: [ "$params.value", { $indexOfArray: [ "$params.name", "deaths" ] } ] } ] 
        }
    }

})
```